# Setting html-attributes in Handlebars/emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to set html-attributes in handlebars in an emberjs application.

```
<input type="{{field.type}}" name="{{field.key}}" id="{{field.name}}" />
```

is what I attempted.

It will outpup html like this:

```
<input type="&lt;script id='metamorph-13-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;text&lt;script id='metamorph-13-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;" name="&lt;script id='metamorph-14-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;entry.810220554&lt;script id='metamorph-14-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;" id="&lt;script id='metamorph-15-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;firstname&lt;script id='metamorph-15-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;">
```

All tags are wrapped in metamorph-tags. I expect this isn't what you are suppose to do. How can I add attributes based on my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bind-attr when you are binding to an element attribute

```
<input {{bind-attr type=field.type name=field.key id=field.name}} />
```

Comment: This works, thou you are suppose to quote the attribute values aswell(my sublime markup breaks unless you use it)

Comment: You don't have to quote the attributes, the core team is moving away from quoting items that aren't static strings.